# SQL Server: Seperate queries return in less than a second but combining those with INTERSECT takes 3 mins

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, intersect

I'm not sure if this is an SQL Server bug or my mistake but here is the situation:

**QUERY 1**

```
select PK FROM PI_INFORM  WHERE RECORD_DATE>DATEADD(hour,-48, GETDATE())
```

this takes less than 0.5 secs and returns 20,000 records

**QUERY 2**

```
SELECT PK FROM dbo.getInformFullTextPKs('"HELLO"')
```

this takes less than 1 secs and returns 500 records

**PROBLEM**
If we join those two queries with INTERSECT, takes more than 3 minutes. Execution plans shows everything is performed using INDEX SEEK.

```
SELECT * FROM PI_INFORM WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE PK IN (

select PK FROM PI_INFORM  WHERE RECORD_DATE>DATEADD(hour,-48, GETDATE())

INTERSECT

SELECT PK FROM PI_INFORM WHERE PK IN (SELECT PK FROM dbo.getInformFullTextPKs('"HELLO"'))
)
```

Comment: Please post the graphical execution plans of all three.

Comment: Are you using NOLOCK on purpose, with full understanding of its limitations, or as a pixie dust turbo button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following query is equivalent and should run faster

```
SELECT * FROM PI_INFORM WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
PK IN (SELECT PK FROM dbo.getInformFullTextPKs('"HELLO"')) AND 
 RECORD_DATE>DATEADD(hour,-48, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Good idea. One of the joins in the original query was redundant.